# Servicemix 7.0.1 - cxf server start too slowly after migration

Tags: cxf, apache-servicemix, cxfrs, camel-cxf

In the context of a migration from ServiceMix 5.1.4 (smx-5) to ServiceMix 7.0.1 (latest stable release) (smx-7) I can see a strange behaviour on my camel routes using the cxf:RsServer

My Camel route looks like this:

```
from("cxfrs:bean:rsServer?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer&synchronous=true")
      .setBody(simple("${body[0]}"))
      .marshal(df)
      .convertBodyTo(String.class)
      .to("{{user.request.endpoint}}")
      .process(checkResponseStatusCode())
      .unmarshal(df);
```

and in the blueprint I have:

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="/user-data/v1" 
     loggingFeatureEnabled="true" depends-on="user-rest-v1" 
     serviceClass="org.my.company.user.rest.v1.resources.UserDataServiceRest" 
     staticSubresourceResolution="true">
      <cxf:providers>
          <bean name="jacksonJsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
          <ref component-id="authenticationFilter" />
      </cxf:providers>
      <cxf:properties>
          <entry key="binding">
              <ref component-id="mySecurityCxfRsBinding" />
          </entry>
      </cxf:properties>
</cxf:rsServer>
```

The class UserDataServiceRest contains the method signature and returning `null` as per old camel specification.
I know it now supports Interface but I am not sure that could be the cause of my issue.

I the version smx-5 all bundles are starting in few seconds (per bundle). In smx-7 the same bundles starts in at least 2 min (per bundle).

While it takes so long, I do not see any activity in the logs.

Note that I also have the issue with server like this:

```
<jaxrs:server id="pingServiceSvc" address="/ping">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref component-id="pingServiceBean" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref component-id="commonExceptionHandler" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <ref component-id="requiredParametersInterceptorBean" />
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
</jaxrs:server>
```

which just answers OK for any reqquest (ping service).

My settings:

- ServiceMix 7.0.1 ()

  - without embedded ActiveMQ
  - installed on RedHat 7 linux
- Java JDK 8 (openJDK build 1.8.0_212-b04)

**UPDATE**

When I tried locally (CentOS 6.10) the bundle (exposing CXF server) starts in around 20 seconds. But when it's deployed on the real server (RHEL 7) it takes more than 2 mins. 
I suspect a network issue but there's nothing in the logs. 
The configuration is almost the same... I am looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

What drives me to the solution was these Warning messages in my logs:

```
2019-06-27T09:24:24Z | WARN  | NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl     | 34 | NamespaceHandler org.apache.camel.blueprint.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler is behaving badly and should be fixed |  |  | 
2019-06-27T09:24:24Z | WARN  | NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl     | 34 | NamespaceHandler org.apache.camel.component.cxf.blueprint.CxfNamespaceHandler is behaving badly and should be fixed |  |  | 
2019-06-27T09:24:24Z | DEBUG | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 34 | Running blueprint container for bundle com.mycompany.user.user-rest-v1/1.0.1.SNAPSHOT in state WaitForNamespaceHandlers |  |  | 
2019-06-27T09:24:24Z | WARN  | NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl     | 34 | Unable to find namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/beans |  |  |
```

It seems there is a problem in the namespace handler in CXF and probably as my server cannot access Internet, there is a timeout.

At this point these was only speculations.

After searching a bit about this subject on Internet, I found [this jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SM-3390) which seems to have a fix in higher version of Camel (since 2.18 and 2.19 according to the JIRA ticket).

Unfortunately there is no more stable release of ServiceMix with a more recent version of Camel than 2.16.5.

Then I tried to upgrade my ServiceMix 7.0.1 with a more recent version of Camel: 2.23.0 (I also tried with 2.24.1 but many of my OSGI dependencies get broken.)

The change I applied is:

1. in file `org.apache.karaf.features.cfg`
   changed the line: `mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.16.5/xml/features, \`
   with: `mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.23.0/xml/features, \`
2. in file `profile.cfg.erb`
   changed the line: `repository.mvn\:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.16.5/xml/features = mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.16.5/xml/features`
   with: `repository.mvn\:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.23.0/xml/features = mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.23.0/xml/features`

After that, 
  * stop your ServiceMix
  * clean cache folder 
  * start the ServiceMix

( or restart the servicemix with `clean` option)

After the full start, when I re-install my feature, all bundles started in a smooth way and faster than before.

Conclusion: the SM-3390 was probably the reason why the bundles were starting slowly.